# A.e. bound for functions in L^infinite

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces, almost-everywhere

Given the following definitions:
$$\mathcal{L}^{\infty} = \{ \ f\in\mathcal{L}^0 \ |\ \exists a\in\mathbb{R}_+: |f| \leq a \ \ \text{a.e.}\}$$
$$\|f\|_{\infty} = \inf_{|f| \leq a \ \ \text{a.e.}} a$$

I'm trying to prove the following property:

If $f\in\mathcal{L}^{\infty}$, then $|f|\leq\|f\|_{\infty}$ a.e.

In particular, I'm having to trouble proving that the set $\{x: |f(x)| > \|f\|_{\infty} +\frac{1}{n}$} has zero measure. What is the procedure to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by definition of "inf", there exsit some $a_n$ satisfies $\{x:|f(x)|> a_n \}$ has measure zero and $\|f\|_{\infty} \le a_n<\|f\|_{\infty} +\frac{1}{n}$, for each $n$.

But we know that 
$$\{x: |f(x)| > \|f\|_{\infty} +\frac{1}{n}\}\subset \{x: |f(x)| > a_n\}$$
which implies that $\{x: |f(x)| > \|f\|_{\infty} +\frac{1}{n}\}$ is also measure zero.